# Installing multiple web servers on a dedicated server. CentOS

Tags: apache, centos, httpd.conf, dedicated-server

I have a dedicated server with 16 IPs. I wanted to know if its possible to install multiple web servers running off the different IPs. What would be the best way to do this? (I believe its possible, because how do web host reseller sites do it?). I am using CentOS 6. Thanks

Comment: I've answered it for you, but this question isn't really about programming and should be at `serverfault.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most host or resellers do not have one IP for each website; instead they use [virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/) to allow one web server to serve multiple domains.

Once a process is listening on port (for example, port 80 which is HTTP) of an interface, that's it - you can't have another server or process listening on the same port.

As you have 16 IPs, you can run 16 servers - one listening on port 80 at each IP address.

Then further, each server can host multiple websites as virtual hosts.

You don't need 16 IPs though - you can host multiple websites using one IP.